# count number of cycles SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in a project and I need help for a specific query in SQL (I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio).
I have a table; the input of the table is a log of a ship's location. I want to know how many travels a specific ship does in a interval of time.

The table has this  format:

```
+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
| ID (PK) | Date (dd/mm/yyyy) | Ship ID | Destination ID (FK) |
+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
|       5 | 02-02-2019        |       5 |                   6 |
|       6 | 02-02-2019        |       6 |                   3 |
|       7 | 03-02-2019        |       5 |                   2 |
+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

The table Destination has a type of attribute: 
1 if is a Start point
2 if is a Delivery point.
I did a formula in excel that checks if the previous point was a Start (type = 1) and the current point is Delivery (type = 2) in that case is one cycle, I don't know how can I do that with a SQL Query

Do you have some tips to do this query?

Comment: What if an end point of a period is between the departure and arrival? Is that counted or not?

Comment: That doesn't happen. The ship leaves the start point and in some time it has to return to the start point, that's a cycle. I need to count how many cycles a ship do.

Comment: Yes but what if an end point of the period you want to count the cycles in is between the departure time and the arrival time? So "half" the cycle is in the period. What to do then?

Comment: Actually that dosen't happend, when a Ship leaves the start point it must go to a delivery point. There's an example (I don't know how to add the table jeje , follow this link: https://pastebin.com/qSFjW4CS ) I don't know if "Cycles" is the correct work to use  It could be "laps"

Comment: So how many cycles are there in the period from 03-02-2019 to 06-02-2019?

Comment: Now I understand your question. There's one cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you actually want to count all occurences where the destintion has a type of 1 and where another destination with type 1 exists for the same ship.

First join the destinations and limit the data to the type 1 and the period wanted. For convenience I put that in a CTE. From that get all records where a previous record exists for the same ship. Group the result by the ship and get the count.

You should get something that looks similar to:

```
WITH x
AS
(
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.date,
       t1.ship_id,
       t1.destination_id
       FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                       ON t2.id = t1.destination_id
       WHERE t2.type = 1
             AND t1.date >= '2019-01-01'
             AND t1.date < '2020-01-01'
)
SELECT x1.ship_id,
       count(*)
       FROM x x1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM x x2
                            WHERE x2.ship_id = x1.ship_id
                                  AND (x2.date < x1.date
                                        OR x2.date = x1.date
                                           AND x2.id < x1.id))
       GROUP BY x1.ship_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

A ship has a start point. It goes to a destination, then maybe other destinations, then back to its start point. One circle. It then leaves again ... until it comes back again. The second circle, etc.

If we look at a certain date range, it may be that we see the start point at the first day or the ship is already travelling and we don't see it hence.

So in order to see how often the ship returned in a date range (i.e. completed a cycle) we should count the ship's start points as of the day after the first day of the date range.

```
select ship_id, count(*)
from location
where location_date between dateadd(day, 1, @startdate) and @enddate
and destination_id in (select destination_id from destination where type = 1)
group by ship_id;
```